# How to write insert query from slect result which return more then one row using max+1 syntax

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to write a SQL like below in DB2.

```
insert into tableA (col1, col2, col3) 
    select max(col1) + 1, '-2', col3 
    from tableA 
    where col2 = -1
```

Here the aim is copy all the record of tableA from -1 to -2 and here col1 is primary key and this should be increment by 1.

Now the problem is the select query will return more then one row like below

```
1001 -2 xyz
1001 -2 pqr
1001 -2 xdc
```

And it is not able to insert as the key is same.

Is there any way I can write the select sql so that it can return like below

```
  1001 -2 xyz
  1002 -2 pqr
  1003 -2 xdc
```

and my insert will work, or is there any alternative way to the same with easiest way.

Note: The table do not have any trigger or some thing to auto increment the primary key.

Comment: I assume you have a `group by col3` on that query.

Comment: I do not have any group by in fact my select query is pretty complex. Please see edit

Comment: why you dont use auto-increment column for your key?

Comment: Note that anything using a `MAX(col) + 1` syntax is _inherently thread unsafe_.  If you have multiple threads doing `INSERT`s, you will get duplicate values.  If you set the isolation level so you don't risk duplicates, you will likely prevent other concurrent updates to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use `row_number()`:

```
insert into tableA ( col1, col2, col3)
    select max(col1) + row_number() over (order by col3), '-2', col3
    from tableA
    where col2 = -1
    group by col3;
```

If you don't have a `group by`, then do:

```
insert into tableA ( col1, col2, col3)
    select  maxcol1 + row_number() over (order by col3), '-2', col3
    from (select a.*, max(col1) over () as maxcol1
          from tableA a
         ) a
    where col2 = -1;
```

The right way to do this is to use a generated auto-incrementing value for `col1`.  This code all has a problem if multiple threads are trying to do inserts at the same time.

Comment: Thank your suggestion on row_number looks prety cool , I will try to use that.

Comment: Can we get at least an acknowledgement that there's concurrency issues with this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !

```
insert into tableA (col1, col2, col3) 
    select (max(col1) + 1) as col1, '-2' as col2, col3 
    from tableA 
    where col2 = -1
```